# How to subscibe to SNS topic with lambda ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I created a lambda function using the `aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function` constructor. Following that I aim to subscribe to a SNS topic I created with boto3. However, one of the arguments needed is the lambda function ARN which I try to get with `dynamodb_lambda.function_arn` but the problem is that the the attributes returns a unresolved token more specifically `${Token[TOKEN.240]}`

Here is a portion of the code to further clarify what I'm doing.

```py
dynamodb_lambda = lambda_.Function(
                        self, #scope
                        "foobar", #id
                        runtime = lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
                        handler = "lambda_handlers.dynamodb_lambda_handler", #filename.methodname at path
                        code    = lambda_.Code.from_asset(path),
                        role    = iam_.Role(    #need this for cloudwatch access
                                    self, #scope
                                    "foobar", #id
                                    assumed_by = iam_.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
                                    managed_policies = [
                                        iam_.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name('DynamoDBFullAccess')
                                    ]
                        )
                    )



client_sns = boto3.client("sns")

response = client_sns.create_topic(
                        Name = c.SNS_TOPIC_NAME,
                        Tags = [ # for easier filtering and searching
                            {
                                'Key': 'CohortStudent',
                                'Value': 'anon'
                            }
                        ])

client_sns.subscribe( 
            TopicArn = response['TopicArn'],
            Protocol = 'lambda',  #usually "email" or "sms", see link above for possible values
            Endpoint = dynamodb_lambda.function_arn
        )
```

The last parameter is where I'm facing trouble. The lambda function isn't created yet so the ARN is a token, but the subscribe function doesn't accept that.

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: Lambda endpoint ARN
```

Please help me understand how to figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect `lambda_.Function(...)` to actually create a lambda function on AWS for you? What are you doing here, are you trying to write a CDK stack or are you trying to write raw boto3 calls, the two cannot just be mixed like you try here.

Comment: I just got into DevOps so I'm a complete noob. I expect it to create a lambda function but after reading your comment I think thats not whats happening. That would also explain why the ARN is returned as a token maybe. Can you please elaborate on the writing CDK vs boto3 calls part? When should I use boto3 calls? I was under the impression that boto3 is a wrapper for aws_cdk and I can use it to write my stack.

Comment: *"boto3 is a wrapper for aws_cdk"* - no no no. Boto3 is a wrapper for AWS API calls, CDK is a wrapper for AWS CloudFormation which is AWS' IaC tool and itself a wrapper for AWS API calls. Within CloudFormation you cannot run any code. You *can* write CDK code, synthesize the template, deploy it and then run boto3 code after it. If you want you CDK to deploy a lambda and subscribe the lambda to SNS you should do the second part in CDK as well.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I have been confused about this for the longest time. Thank you again. That clears up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As luk2302 has commented, using boto3 calls to subscribe to a SNS Topic created using aws_cdk is wrong. A simple fix would be to use subscribe to the lambda using aws_cdk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).